Meta Quest 3 Ar Scan export
I want to develop an indoor routing app for my school using AR, but I don’t have an iPhone equipped with LiDAR. Somehow, I need to scan the floors of my school. My idea is to use my Meta Quest 3, but I’m unsure how to export the room and floor scans. Ideally, I’d like to import these scans into Unity. However, I'm facing an issue where the Meta Quest 3 sometimes breaks during the scanning process, making it difficult to scan an entire floor at once.
I previously tried using my iPhone 11 with Vuforia's Area Target Creator, but it didn’t work because my device lacks LiDAR.
Could you help me improve my scanning process and find a solution to scan entire floors successfully?
